# R code for robust ridge regression

Tags: outliers, multicollinearity, ridge-regression, robust

I am having trouble in searching for the MSE value in using robust ridge regression. The robust estimators that i used is LTS and MM. However, when both robust estimators were applied to ridge, the constant, K for each estimators are about the same. Same goes for the MSE values. The weird part is the OLS is found to be good in a data where multicollinearity and outliers exist. Does anyone have the right code in applying robust ridge regression to a real data such as longley data?

Please help. Thanks.